# Compute annual rate using a DataFrame and pct_change()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column inside a DataFrame that I want to use in order to perform the operation:

```
n = step/12
step = 3
t1 = step - 1
pd.DataFrame(100*((df[t1+step::step]['Column'].values / df[t1:-t1:step]['Column'].values)**(1/n) - 1))
```

A possible set of values for the column of interest could be:

```
>>> df['Column']

0          NaN
1          NaN
2       7469.5
3          NaN
4          NaN
5       7537.9
6          NaN
7          NaN
8       7655.2
9          NaN
10         NaN
11      7712.6
12         NaN
13         NaN
14      7784.1
15         NaN
16         NaN
17      7819.8
18         NaN
19         NaN
20      7898.6
21         NaN
22         NaN
23      7939.5
24         NaN
25         NaN
26      7995.0
27         NaN
28         NaN
29      8084.7
...
```

So `df[t1+step::step]['Column']` would give us:

```
>>> df[5::3]['Column']

5       7537.9
8       7655.2
11      7712.6
14      7784.1
17      7819.8
20      7898.6
23      7939.5
26      7995.0
29      8084.7
32      8158.0
35      8292.7
38      8339.3
41      8449.5
44      8498.3
47      8610.9
50      8697.7
53      8766.1
56      8831.5
59      8850.2
62      8947.1
65      8981.7
68      8983.9
71      8907.4
74      8865.6
77      8934.4
80      8977.3
83      9016.4
86      9123.0
89      9223.5
92      9313.2
...
```

And lastly `df[t1:-t1:step]['Column']`

```
>>> df[2:-2:3]['Column']
2       7469.5
5       7537.9
8       7655.2
11      7712.6
14      7784.1
17      7819.8
20      7898.6
23      7939.5
26      7995.0
29      8084.7
32      8158.0
35      8292.7
38      8339.3
41      8449.5
44      8498.3
47      8610.9
50      8697.7
53      8766.1
56      8831.5
59      8850.2
62      8947.1
65      8981.7
68      8983.9
71      8907.4
74      8865.6
77      8934.4
80      8977.3
83      9016.4
86      9123.0
89      9223.5
...
```

With these values what we expect is the following output:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(100*((df[5::3]['Column'].values / df[2:-2:3]['Column'].values)**4 -1))

0    3.713517
1    6.371352
2    3.033171
3    3.760103
4    1.847168
5    4.092131
6    2.087397
7    2.825602
8    4.563898
9    3.676223
10   6.769944
11   2.266778
12   5.391516
13   2.330287
14   5.406150
15   4.093476
16   3.182961
17   3.017786
18   0.849662
19   4.452016
20   1.555866
21   0.098013
22  -3.362834
23  -1.863919
24   3.140454
25   1.934544
26   1.753587
27   4.813692
28   4.479794
29   3.947179
```

Since this reminds a lot of what `pct_change()` does I was wondering if I could achieve the same result by doing something like:

```
>>> df['Column'].pct_change(periods=step)**(1/n) * 100
```

Until now I am getting incorrect outputs though. Is it possible to use `pct_change()` and achieve the same result?